# Is there a way to change set few options before fetching the html from site in jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

I want to fetch fare details from a site which i will get only if i fetch the HTML after setting the required radio button.Is there a way in jsoup to make the option selected and fetch it so that i can get the populated fare details.

Comment: It looks like JavaScrip. In that case Jsoup will not be able to help you. In case it is Ajax call which loads new html content you can try to observe where this call is sent and what data it returns, and then try to parse it. Anyway it is hart do help you without seeing actual page.

Comment: select the radio button and then pass that URL. You need to observe the pattern of the URL and understand how it changes when some events occurs on the page. Then, you can create the type of URL you need.

Comment: There no other call going after the selection of radio button as the logic written in the JS

Answer (score 0):

Jsoup only fetches and parses HTML, it doesn't execute javascript or perform any Web browser style interaction.

If you need something like this you will need to remote control a real Web browser with a tool like [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org), or use an embedded one like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org).

Comment: ... or Selenium web driver.

Comment: Thanks - I did link to the Selenium site, will mention it by name as well.